# How do I keep a variable open and not refill it when running a Python script?

Tags: python, file, memory

I want to ask you how I can keep a variable open and not refill it when I execute the script. As an example, I read the file and assigned all of its lines to a variable. Then, I created some processes to interact with data executed from a file. I realized I needed to change something in my process after running the file, so I changed a few lines and ran the script again. The file is large, and I need to wait for it to upload, so I considered how I could keep the variable that refers to this file open at all times and easily make changes to my script without having to wait so long for it to upload.

```
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy import spatial

# This is the variable that I want to keep always open
embeddings_dict = {}

# This is the current file
filename = "/some_filename"
with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in tqdm(range(len(lines))):
        values = lines[i].split()
        word = values[0]
        vector = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
        embeddings_dict[word] = vector


# This is the process
def find_closest_embeddings_euc(embedding):
    return sorted(embeddings_dict.keys(),
                  key=lambda word: spatial.distance.euclidean(embeddings_dict[word], embedding))


print(find_closest_embeddings_euc(embeddings_dict['software'])[:10])
```

I expect to understand how can I make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really persist memory in RAM once a process finishes. What you're describing is a classic workflow in the ML community (having to load in some huge dataset in memory and then apply and tweak a series of transformations to it) and a notebook environment is usually the answer.

You can check out how to setup your environment at either of these links:

1. https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/notebook-classic.html
2. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks (I recommend this one if you are already using VS Code)

Once you create your first notebook, you can add two cells to it - one for the data loading and another for the transformations. Now you can execute them independently - you can load your data once and apply the transformations and experiment with them as many times as you'd like.